# Analog of free monads for Profunctors

Tags: haskell, free-monad, profunctor

We can define `data Free f a = Pure a | Free (f (Free f a))` and so have `Functor f => Monad (Free f)`.

If we define
`data T f a b = R a | S b | T (f a (T f a b))` have we some analogous `M` so `Profunctor f => M (T f a)`, where `class Profunctor f where dimap :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> f b c -> f a d`?

I've been wondering ever since i noted [`Data.Comp.Term.Context`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/compdata-0.10.1/docs/Data-Comp-Term.html#t:Cxt) and `Free` are isomorphic about a potential analog for [`Data.Comp.Param.Term.Context`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/compdata-param-0.9/docs/Data-Comp-Param-Term.html#t:Context).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a more appropriate notion of making a free thing from a profunctor. Then we can work by analogy.

A free monoid, Y, generated by a set X is can be thought of as the solution to the equation "Y=1+XY". In Haskell notation that is

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

A free monad, M, generated by the functor F can be thought of as the solution to the equation "M=1+FM" where the product "FM' is the composition of functors. 1 is just the identity functor. In Haskell notation that is

```
data Free f a = Pure a | Free (f (Free a))
```

Making something free from a profunctor P should look like a solution, A, to "A=1+PA". The product "PA" is the standard [composition of profunctors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart-gtk-1.1/docs/Data-Profunctor-Composition.html). The 1 is the "identity" profunctor, `(->)`. So we get

```
data Free p a b = Pure (a -> b) | forall x.Free (p a x) (Free p x b)
```

This is also a profunctor:

```
instance Profunctor b => Profunctor (Free b) where
    lmap f (Pure g) = Pure (g . f)
    lmap f (Free g h) = Free (lmap f g) h
    rmap f (Pure g) = Pure (f . g)
    rmap f (Free g h) = Free g (rmap f h)
```

If the profunctor is strong then so is the free version:

```
instance Strong p => Strong (Free p) where
    first' (Pure f) = Pure (first' f)
    first' (Free f g) = Free (first' f) (first' g)
```

But what actually is `Free p`? It's actually a thing called a [pre-arrow](http://www.fceia.unr.edu.ar/~mauro/pubs/Notions_of_Computation_as_Monoids.pdf). Restricting, free strong profunctors are arrows:

```
instance Profunctor p => Category (Free p) where
    id = Pure id
    Pure f . Pure g = Pure (f . g)
    Free g h . Pure f = Free (lmap f g) h
    Pure f . Free g h = Free g (Pure f . h)
    f . Free g h = Free g (f . h)

instance (Profunctor p, Strong p) => Arrow (Free p) where
    arr = Pure
    first = first'
```

Intuitively you can think of an element of a profunctor `P a b` as taking an `a`-ish thing to a `b`-ish thing, the canonical example being given by `(->)`. `Free P` is an unevaluated chain of these elements with compatible (but unobservable) intermediate types.

Comment: Interesting, but why restrict to profunctors of the form Hask^op*Hask -> Hask?

Comment: @mnish'cos that's what Haskell's Profunctor type class is. Generalising to other classes is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

So i think i figured it out: `M ~ Monad` ☺

```
instance Profunctor f => Functor (T f a) where
    fmap f (In m) = In (dimap id (fmap f) m)
    fmap f (Hole x) = Hole (f x)
    fmap f (Var v) = Var v

instance Profunctor f => Applicative (T f a) where
    pure = Hole
    (<*>) = ap

instance Profunctor f => Monad (T f a) where
    In m >>= f = In ((>>= f) <$> m)
    Hole x >>= f = f x
    Var v >>= _ = Var v
```

Seems obvious in hindthought.

Comment: Yes, because profunctors are just functors with an additional, contravariant parameter. Your `T` doesn't actually make use of `f`'s profunctor-ness, just its functor-ness: you're using `id` as the first argument to `dimap`. `T` is basically just `Free` with an extra parameter